# Arduino - code not being uploaded to board

Tags: arduino

I recently bought a new Arduino uno board from ebay and I am having trouble uploading code to the board. When I try to upload, I receive the following error message after a couple of minutes:

```
Sketch uses 1,066 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xdc
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xdc
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xdc
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

I would like to ask what this error message means and if there is a way to resolve the issue?

I have tried searching for the problem and attempted various solutions I found on the Arduino website, but none appear to be working. I have checked the "Port" and "Board" settings on the IDE and they appear to be correct. As it is a new board, I hope that it is not broken in anyway. If anyone recognizes this error message, any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have anything hooked up to digital pins 0 or 1? (Might be 1&2....the first two) -- those are used for serial.

Comment: no there is nothing in those pins.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug on the atmega compiler on certain linux versions, but it can be worked around by resetting your board shortly before uploading your sketch:

- Reset the arduino by clicking the button on the board
- Count to 3
- Click upload on the IDE